# How to return from find in nodejs,mongoose mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While find() element in mongodb collection, using mongoose, the console.log doesn't executed in the Test.js

In the **Test.js**, the **console.log**  doesn't print the data from the MongoDb collection

```
var model =  require('./model');
model.findbyTag('java',function (data)
{
    console.log(data)
});
```

The **Model.js** has the following entry

```
exports.findbyTag = function(tag,out)
{
    var condtion = {"tag" : tag}
     Tag.find(condtion,function(err,out){
          //  console.log(out);
             if (err) console.log('Error returning Tag!');
            else {
               return out;
            }
        });
}
```

When i uncomment the console.log file in the **Model.js** , it's log the data matched in the find query,

The callback in **test.js** file doesn't executed, did i successfully returning data from the **Model.js**, what wrong i'm doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model.js findbyTag  method is returning function object instead of executing callback function . Also, queried document need to be passed as an argument to callback function. It can be modified like:

```
exports.findbyTag = function(tag,out)
{
    var condtion = {"tag" : tag}
     Tag.find(condtion,function(err,doc){
          //  console.log(doc);
             if (err) console.log('Error returning Tag!');
            else {
               out(doc);
            }
        });
}
```